# PicklingError when adding to memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use memcache for the first time on App Engine and am hitting a "PicklingError".

The first place I've tried memcache is on the site's home page where I grab content from the datastore:

```
def get(self):
    content = memcache.get('home:content')
    if content is None:
        all_content = Content.all()
        all_content.order("-views")
        all_content.filter('published =', True)
        content = all_content.run(batch_size=5, limit=5)
        memcache.add(key='home:content', value=content, time=120)
```

(Note that this works fine without me trying to put the content Query object into memcache. Here's the error it hits on the last line (memcache.add...):

```
PicklingError: Pickling of datastore_query.Batcher is unsupported.
```

Here's the model for Content:

```
class Content(db.Model):
    category = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content_type = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    published = db.BooleanProperty(default = False)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    abstract = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    summary = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    URL = db.LinkProperty(required = True)
    youtube_id = db.StringProperty(required = False)
    thumbnail = db.LinkProperty(required = True)
    post_author = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    author_url = db.LinkProperty(required = False)
    date_post = db.DateTimeProperty(required = True, auto_now_add = True)
    date_source = db.DateTimeProperty(required = False)    
    # todo: split out to use decent shardedcounter approach
    views = db.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
    up_votes = db.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
    down_votes = db.IntegerProperty(default = 0)    
    def votes(self):
        return self.up_votes - self.down_votes
```

I'm struggling to figure out what a PicklingError is and how that might relate to trying to store a Query object into memcache. My questions:
What am I doing wrong?
Is this because I'm trying to cache the iterator? 
Is there any value in caching the Query object and needing to call .run() on it every page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py) for `memcache`.

In a nutshell, this occurs because your value has to be serialized in a simple way, so by default `pickle` (actually `cPickle`) is used to serialize the object you pass in.

When `add` is called, `_set_with_policy` is called which subsequently calls `_set_multi_async_with_policy`. In `_set_multi_async_with_policy`, the key-value pairs are passing in as `mapping` and are [serialized in a loop](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py?r=302#968):

```
for key, value in mapping.iteritems():
  server_key = _key_string(key, key_prefix, user_key)
  stored_value, flags = _validate_encode_value(value, self._do_pickle)
```

In the helper method `_validate_encode_value`, if the object passed in is not something recognizable such as `int`, `bool`, `str`, the method [attempts to pickle](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py?r=302#226) the object:

```
else:
  stored_value = do_pickle(value)
  flags |= TYPE_PICKLED
```

**UPDATE:** When you call run you get an [iterator object](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py?r=302#2073) back which contains certain objects contained in your query. If you'd like to pickle just the results, you can just cast this iterator to a list via

```
content = list(all_content.run(batch_size=5, limit=5))
```

If you'd like the other pieces kept around, you'll need some sort of custom pickler. As [you can see](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py?r=302#2510) in `Batcher`:

```
  def __getstate__(self):
    raise pickle.PicklingError(
        'Pickling of datastore_query.Batch is unsupported.')
```

most of the classes defined in `datastore_query` -- the very same classes that define the majority of the query behavior -- strongly discourage pickling by throwing a `PicklingError` when `__getstate__` is called. If you've never played around with it, `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` are custom methods that help to pickle and unpickle objects.

Comment: Thanks for the detail - this definitely helps my understanding of why it's failing, but not what I should be doing to make it work.